# How to return json object having particular value in java?

Tags: java, arrays, json, hashmap, multimap

This is what I have as a json and I have one condition here to ignore the object which has object_name:[parent],I had tried somthing which didnt worked out can someone help me with the same

```
    [
  {
    "object_group": "Trans",
    "permission_values": [
      {
        "object_type": "Trans",
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "View": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "Invoice"
        ]
      },
      {
        "object_type": "Trans",
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "View": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "parent"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "object_group": "General",
    "permission_values": [
      {
        "object_type": "General",
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "View": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "Customer"
        ]
      },
      {
        "object_type": "General",
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "Delete": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "Product"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is the actual Thing I tried which I got as from one I have one condition here to ignore the object which has object_name :[parent]

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

public class TestData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {

         String input = "{\"JSON_OBJECT\":[{\"object_type\":\"Trans\",\"permission_type\":[{\"View\":true}],\"object_name\":[\"Invoice\"]},{\"object_type\":\"General\",\"permission_type\":[{\"View\":true}],\"object_name\":[\"Customer\"]},{\"object_type\":\"Trans\",\"permission_type\":[{\"View\":true}],\"object_name\":[\"Payments\"]},{\"object_type\":\"General\",\"permission_type\":[{\"Delete\":true}],\"object_name\":[\"Product\"]}]}";
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(input);
            Iterator<JsonNode> jsonObject = jsonNode.get("JSON_OBJECT").iterator();
            ObjectNode objectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();

            while (jsonObject.hasNext()) {
                JsonNode node = jsonObject.next();
                String object_type = node.path("object_type").asText();
                if (objectNode.has(object_type)) {
                    JsonNode objectTypeNode = objectNode.get(object_type);
                    JsonNode permission_values = objectTypeNode.path("permission_values");
                    if (!permission_values.isMissingNode()) {
                        ObjectNode permissionNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
                        node.fields().forEachRemaining(kv -> permissionNode.set(kv.getKey(),kv.getValue()));
                        ((ArrayNode) permission_values).add(permissionNode);
                    } else {
                        ObjectNode permissionNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
                        node.fields().forEachRemaining(kv -> permissionNode.set(kv.getKey(),kv.getValue()));
                        ((ArrayNode) permission_values).add(permissionNode);
                    }
                } else {
                    ArrayNode permissionArrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();
                    ObjectNode permissionNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
                    node.fields().forEachRemaining(kv -> permissionNode.set(kv.getKey(),kv.getValue()));
                    permissionArrayNode.add(permissionNode);
                    ObjectNode permNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
                    permNode.set("permission_values", permissionArrayNode);
                    objectNode.set(object_type, permNode);
                }
            }
            ArrayNode arrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();
            objectNode.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(key ->{
                ObjectNode node = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
                node.put("object_group",key);
                objectNode.get(key).fields().forEachRemaining(kv -> node.set(kv.getKey(),kv.getValue()));
                arrayNode.add(node);
            });
            System.out.println(arrayNode.toString());
    }
}
```

Expected output:-
can someone pls help me to get this output ..

```
[
  {
    "object_group": "Trans",
    "permission_values": [
      {
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "View": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "Invoice"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "object_group": "General",
    "permission_values": [
      {
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "View": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "Customer"
        ]
      },
      {
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "Delete": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "Product"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I hope the programmers working on the payment tools I use will never share the json structure from the model of those applications... Better to clean your JSON example for the sake of your user's safety

Comment: this is dummy json ,nothing to worry .. I take precautions while posting anything officially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to create POJOs, you have to play with general json object or Map.
I have used Jackson library to get the output. Please see If this is what you want.
Since expected output is of not a proper json, I have modified to get below output.

```
    String input = "{\"JSON_OBJECT\":[{\"object_type\":\"Trans\",\"permission_type\":[{\"View\":true}],\"object_name\":[\"Invoice\"]},{\"object_type\":\"General\",\"permission_type\":[{\"View\":true}],\"object_name\":[\"Customer\"]},{\"object_type\":\"Trans\",\"permission_type\":[{\"View\":true}],\"object_name\":[\"Payments\"]},{\"object_type\":\"General\",\"permission_type\":[{\"Delete\":true}],\"object_name\":[\"Product\"]}]}";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(input);
    Iterator<JsonNode> jsonObject = jsonNode.get("JSON_OBJECT").iterator();
    ObjectNode objectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();

                while (jsonObject.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode node = jsonObject.next();
            String object_type = node.path("object_type").asText();
            if (objectNode.has(object_type)) {
                JsonNode objectTypeNode = objectNode.get(object_type);
                JsonNode permission_values = objectTypeNode.path("permission_values");
                if (!permission_values.isMissingNode()) {
                    ObjectNode permissionNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
                    node.fields().forEachRemaining(kv -> addIfRequired(permissionNode, kv));
                    ((ArrayNode) permission_values).add(permissionNode);
                } else {
                    ObjectNode permissionNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
                    node.fields().forEachRemaining(kv -> addIfRequired(permissionNode, kv));
                    ((ArrayNode) permission_values).add(permissionNode);
                }
            } else {
                ArrayNode permissionArrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();
                ObjectNode permissionNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
                node.fields().forEachRemaining(kv -> addIfRequired(permissionNode, kv));
                permissionArrayNode.add(permissionNode);
                ObjectNode permNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
                permNode.set("permission_values", permissionArrayNode);
                objectNode.set(object_type, permNode);
            }
        }

    System.out.println(objectNode.toString());
```

**Edit 3**

```
private static void addIfRequired(ObjectNode permissionNode, Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> kv) {
    if (!("object_name".equalsIgnoreCase(kv.getKey()) && kv.getValue().get(0).asText().toLowerCase().contains("parent"))) {
        permissionNode.set(kv.getKey(), kv.getValue());
    }
}
```

//output

```
{
  "Trans": {
    "permission_values": [
      {
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "View": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "Invoice"
        ]
      },
      {
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "View": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "Payments"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "General": {
    "permission_values": [
      {
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "View": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "Customer"
        ]
      },
      {
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "Delete": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "Product"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Edit: Assuming you need array as output**

```
    ArrayNode arrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();
    objectNode.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(key ->{
        ObjectNode node = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        node.put("object_group",key);
        objectNode.get(key).fields().forEachRemaining(kv -> node.set(kv.getKey(),kv.getValue()));
        arrayNode.add(node);
    });
    System.out.println(arrayNode.toString());
```

//output

```
[
  {
    "object_group": "Trans",
    "permission_values": [
      {
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "View": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "Invoice"
        ]
      },
      {
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "View": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "Payments"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "object_group": "General",
    "permission_values": [
      {
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "View": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "Customer"
        ]
      },
      {
        "permission_type": [
          {
            "Delete": true
          }
        ],
        "object_name": [
          "Product"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: this is right just need two help first is I want to add { "object_group":"General": something like this and other for permission_value to be added , can u pls help me with that , rest everything is fine ..its working , u can refer the edited response and ques for better view

Comment: @NiteshBhushan again the output is not a proper json. can you please correct it ?

Comment: where to add this edit portion your output is correct , can u pls edit your answer and add the edit portion what you have shown externally ..this is the same what I required

Comment: 2nd output is extension of 1st output. So you need complete code. Just replace System.out.println(objectNode.toString()); with edited code.

Comment: replace two lines  permissionNode.set("permission_type", node.get("permission_type"));
                permissionNode.set("object_name", node.get("object_name")); with node.fields().forEachRemaining(kv -> permissionNode.set(kv.getKey(),kv.getValue()));

Comment: edited the answer to include all the key values present in JSON_OBJECT key

Comment: Added new method which will ignore if object_name is parent

Comment: copy all the code, it should work fine. No argument needs to be passed. Regarding adding new field, it is as easy as setting node.set() method. Please try to do it yourself to get better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is a bit fundamentally wrong, it would be better if you utilize [gson library](https://github.com/google/gson) to get Objects which you can easily get the required values from once initiated.

I recommend using [this tool](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to easily get POJO object in gson notation as well.

example generated three classes from the tool:

```
-----------------------------------com.example.JsonObject.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class JsonObject {

@SerializedName("object_type")
@Expose
private String objectType;
@SerializedName("permission_type")
@Expose
private List<PermissionType> permissionType = null;
@SerializedName("object_name")
@Expose
private List<String> objectName = null;

public String getObjectType() {
return objectType;
}

public void setObjectType(String objectType) {
this.objectType = objectType;
}

public List<PermissionType> getPermissionType() {
return permissionType;
}

public void setPermissionType(List<PermissionType> permissionType) {
this.permissionType = permissionType;
}

public List<String> getObjectName() {
return objectName;
}

public void setObjectName(List<String> objectName) {
this.objectName = objectName;
}

}
```

```
-----------------------------------com.example.MyClass.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class MyClass {

@SerializedName("JSON_OBJECT")
@Expose
private List<JsonObject> jsonObject = null;

public List<JsonObject> getJsonObject() {
return jsonObject;
}

public void setJsonObject(List<JsonObject> jsonObject) {
this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
}

}
```

```
-----------------------------------com.example.PermissionType.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class PermissionType {

@SerializedName("View")
@Expose
private Boolean view;
@SerializedName("Delete")
@Expose
private Boolean delete;

public Boolean getView() {
return view;
}

public void setView(Boolean view) {
this.view = view;
}

public Boolean getDelete() {
return delete;
}

public void setDelete(Boolean delete) {
this.delete = delete;
}

}
```

So when you fetch the response array from your REST/Api methods, you could simply do something like:

```
...
..
.
JSONObject responseObject = resObj.getJSONObject("whole_response_api");

     
     Type listType = new TypeToken<MyClass>() {
     }.getType();
     MyClass javaObject = gson.fromJson(responseObject.toString(), listType));

     String objectTypeOf1st = javaObject.getJsonObject(1).getObjectType();

...
..
.
```

NOTE: Did not compile this, so syntax could we way-off, but I hope you understood my point though.

EDIT: [This video by CodingInFlow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-kcvxYZrB4) explains the concept of De-serializing and serializing splendidly if you want to take a look.

Comment: syntax is too way off , I am expecting some straight forward answer . In this surely in one way or another I am surely going to get stuck, but thanks anyway